In elastic, how can I start a new transaction in the distributed listeners?
We have a homegrown messaging system that distributes messages ala Kafka.
Current implementation starts a transaction on the messaging nodes and the node passes the message over to an app for processing and it carries along the transaction.  So, currently all tracing is related back to whatever is used in the node (all messages in a big ball) vs the detail wanted in the application, e.g. how long does it take to process a message of type x vs type y.
Is there a way to start a new Trace in the receiving application?  More, it would be great to relate the message handling in the node to the message handling in the application.
